# Python + opencv with PyCharm- 'opencv' has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, imread

A similar question to mine exists, however it does not answer my question.

Here is what I am working with:

Python v. 3.6.2

opencv 1.0.1

PyCharm Community Edition 2017 .2.2

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

I'm trying to use imread for image processing. I've looked at the documentation and I am using the function correctly. Here is the test code that comes with the opencv library:

```
import opencv
img = cv.imread('background.png')
if img is None:
    print("Image not loaded!")
else:
    print("Image is loaded!")
```

I can see my python files and and modules in the project explorer. When I run the code, I get the following error:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/lmc/Desktop/pywerk/opencvpractice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lmc/Desktop/pywerk/opencvpractice", line 4, in 
    img = cv.imread('background.png')
**AttributeError: module 'opencv' has no attribute 'imread'**

I've tried everything from reinstalling python and the opencv module to switching python versions to 2.7 (and using the respective opencv module) and I get the same error.

Is there some sort of system configuration I could be missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the deprecated OpenCV 1.x instead of OpenCV 2.x or 3.x with the `cv2` module? The `cv2` module uses a `numpy` backend for image storing so it's far superior for working with the data. Anyways, the answer below should fix you up; you're importing `opencv` yet using the namespace `cv` which you haven't defined.

Comment: OpenCV **1.0.1**? [No such version was released](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog_v10-v21#10), but even it it was, it would predate Python 3.0 by about 2 years. Seems like some nonsense... perhaps [this bit of junk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv/1.0.1) in the package index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a combination of several of these suggestions; if I could give the answer props to Alexander Reynolds that would be the most accurate. I was following an outdated tutorial and ended up with an outdated version of opencv. I downloaded opencv using the instructions here, for anyone else who is looking for the exact commands:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.1.0.3

Here is what I ended up with:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('background.png')
if img is None:
    print("Image not loaded!")
else:
    print("Image is loaded!")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try with `opencv.imread`?

```
import opencv
img = opencv.imread('background.png')
if img is None:
    print("Image not loaded!")
else:
    print("Image is loaded!")
```

or alternatively `import opencv as cv`:

```
import opencv as cv
img = cv.imread('background.png')
if img is None:
    print("Image not loaded!")
else:
    print("Image is loaded!")
```

Answer (score 1):

For OpenCV, it should be imported as

```
import cv
```

or 
`import cv2` (If you want to change to opencv V2.x or 3.x)